# Loop for Deleting Sheets gets runtime error

Tags: excel, for-loop, vba

I created a for loop to delete sheets from a workbook. The block of code adds a workbook and counts the number of sheets in that workbook, which by default is usually three (3). So, according to the IF function, it should delete sheet2 and sheet 3. However, it brings up the runtime error after deleting sheet2. I'm a beginner to VBA, and I do not know what to do. Please help. Thank you very much. 
(Note: If c is equal to 2, it works fine and deletes sheet3. The error only occurs when c is equal to 1.)

```
      c= 1
      Dim Wbk As Workbook
      Set Wbk = Workbooks.Add
      i = Wbk.Worksheets.count = 3
      Application.DisplayAlerts = False
      If c < i Then
         For j = (c + 1) To 3
          Sheets(j).Delete
         Next j
      ElseIf c > i Then
      Wbk.Worksheets.Add after:=Wbk.Worksheets("sheet3"), count:=(c - i)
      Else: End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Sheets have an index starting at 1. So a workbook with 3 sheets has 1-3. The issue here is that once you delete sheet two(2) you now only have 1-2 (1 is sheet1 and 2 is sheet3). So when you are incrementing to 3 there is no longer a sheet with the index of 3.

You want something more like this.

```
  c= 1
  Dim Wbk As Workbook
  Set Wbk = Workbooks.Add
  Dim i As Integer
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False

  For i = Wbk.Worksheets.count To 1 step -1
      Sheets(i).Delete
  Next iIndex
```